# How to pass an object from a nested directive with isolated scope to parent controller scope in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive treeview which contains a nested directive (being the branches) of each item rendered.

In the scope of both directives I have declared two parameters that should be talking to the parent controller.

`filter: '&'` //binds the method filter within the nested directive (branch) to the method doSomething() in the tree directive attribute which is bound to the html directive that binds to the controller.

`iobj: '='` is the two way binding paramter that should be passing the scoped object to the controller. (but currently isn't)

Directive:

```
app.directive('tree', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', 
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            t: '=src',
            filter: '&',
            iobj: '='
        },
        controller: 'treeController',
        template: '<ul><branch ng-repeat="c in t.children" iobj="object" src="c" filter="doSomething()"></branch></ul>'
    };
});

app.directive('branch', function($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E', 
        replace: true, 
        scope: {
            b: '=src',
            filter: '&',
            iobj: '='
        },

        template: '<li><input type="checkbox" ng-click="innerCall()"  ng-hide="visible" /><a>{{ b.name }}</a></li>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           var has_children = angular.isArray(scope.b.children);
            scope.visible = has_children;
            if (has_children) {
                element.append('<tree src="b"></tree>');
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
            element.on('click', function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                if (has_children) {
                    element.toggleClass('collapsed');
                }
            });
            scope.innerCall = function () {
                scope.iobj = scope.b;

                console.log(scope.iobj);
                scope.filter();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="treeController">
    <tree src="myList" iobj="object" filter="doSomething()"></tree>

    <a ng-click="clicked()"> link</a>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("treeController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.object = {};
    $scope.doSomething = function () {
        var item = $scope.object;
        //alert('call from directive');
        console.log(item);
   }

   $scope.clicked = function () {
       alert('clicked');
   }
...
```

Currently I **can** invoke the function `$scope.doSomething` from the directive to the controller. So I know that I have access to the controllers scope from the directive. What I cannot figure out is how to pass an object as a parameter from the directive back to the controller. When I run this code, `$scope.object`
is always an empty object.

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions on how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` directive binding supports parameter passing. Given your example

```
scope.filter({message: 'Hello', anotherMessage: 'Good'})
```

The `message` and `anotherMessage` become local variables in the expression bound to directive:

```
<tree src="myList" iobj="object" filter="doSomething(anotherMessage, message)"></tree>
```

Here's a sample [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j0eZUhTBmFP4mtz8zTb2?p=preview) where the callback parameters are set inside a template.

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) clearly states that:

> Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an
>   expression to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of
>   local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For
>   example, if the expression is `increment(amount)` then we can specify
>   the amount value by calling the `localFn` as `localFn({amount: 22})`.